# assigning to gslice_array gives runtime error

Tags: c++, valarray

I'm trying to construct a class derived from [`std::valarray<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) to use my own methods on it. I have encountered a problem about assigning values using [operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_at). After a lot of effort, I think I finally detected the problem. While assigning to [`std::slice_array<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice_array) does not constitude a problem, assigning to [`std::gslice_array<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/gslice_array) does.

Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <valarray>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const size_t rows = 16;
    const size_t cols = 24;
    assert(rows%8 == 0);
    assert(cols%8 == 0);

    // return b_th 8x8 block
    auto get_block = [&rows, &cols](size_t b) -> std::gslice {
        return std::gslice((b / (cols/8))*8*cols + (b % (cols/8))*8, {8, 8}, {cols, 1});
    };

    // zeros(rows, cols) but 1D
    std::valarray<int> v(0, rows*cols);

    auto print = [&rows, &cols, &v]() -> void {
        for (size_t i=0; i<rows; i++) {
            for (size_t j=0; j<cols; j++)
                std::cout << " " << v[i*cols + j];
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    };
    print();

    // this is OK
    v[get_block(1)] = 1;
    print();

    // this is also OK
    std::slice_array<int> s = v[std::slice(2*cols, cols, 1)];
    s = 2;
    print();

    // ???
    std::gslice_array<int> g = v[get_block(3)];
//  g = 3;  // this line causes runtime error
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: What compiler are you using? My assumptions are that `g` uses references to elements of temporary `gslice` instance produced by `get_block`. I can reproduce the same issue with `G++`. But on MSVC works fine. For G++, problem disappears when  we create named `gslice` instance: `auto b = get_block(3); std::gslice_array<int> g = v[b]; g = 3;`, this works fine.

Comment: @rafix07 Yes, I'm using G++. The problem is solved when creating a new `gslice` instance as you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use g++, you have dangling reference, which leads to undefined behaviour and crash.

It is a bug in g++.

In this line:

```
std::gslice_array<int> g = v[get_block(3)];
```

by calling `get_block(3)` temporary instance of `gslice` is created.
Method `valarray::operator[](gslice)` is called taking this temporary `gslice`. 
Let's look at its implementation:

```
template<typename _Tp>
inline gslice_array<_Tp>
valarray<_Tp>::operator[](const gslice& __gs)
{
  return gslice_array<_Tp> (_Array<_Tp>(_M_data), __gs._M_index->_M_index);
}
```

it takes reference to const `gslice` so temporary instance of `gslice` can be bound to `__gs`, 
when returning from this method, object of `gslice_array` is created by:

```
  template<typename _Tp>
    inline
    gslice_array<_Tp>::gslice_array(_Array<_Tp> __a,
                    const valarray<size_t>& __i)
    : _M_array(__a), _M_index(__i) {}
```

where `_M_array` and `_M_index` of `gslice_array` are defined as:

```
  _Array<_Tp>              _M_array;
  const valarray<size_t>&  _M_index; // <------------- here is reference !
```

To `_M_index` of `gslice_array` is assigned `__gs._M_index->_M_index`. What is `__gs._M_index` ?
It is a inner struct of `gslice` named as `_Indexer`. It uses a reference counter mechanism
to prolong lifetime itself. Reference counter of `_Indexer` can be increased only if 
`gslice` is copied (by copy constructor or copy assignment operator), but none of these 
operation are performed in this code. Hence, when `gslice` as temporary object is deleted, `_M_index` of `__gs` is deleted too, and finally dangling reference occurs.

Where is bug? Keeping reference to member of indexer, which is deleted when `gslice` is deleted.
It would not happen, if indexer held pointer to valarray instead of reference.
Storing of references is not transitional.

As workaround, create L-value instance of `gslice` as follows:

```
auto b = get_block(3);
std::gslice_array<int> g = v[b];
g = 3;
print();
```

then, everything works fine.