# Why do some assignment operators for the helper classes of std::valarray return void?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, proxy-classes, valarray

For example, the assignment operators for `std::slice_array`:

```
void operator=(const valarray<T>&) const; //#1
void operator=(const T&) const; //#2
const slice_array& operator=(const slice_array&) const; //#3
```

`#1` and `#2` return `void`, but `#3` returns `const slice_array&`.

It prohibits some code, such as:

```
std::valarray<int> va{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
va[std::slice(3, 2, 2)] = va[std::slice(0, 2, 2)] = va[0];
```

**Why?**

Comment: Whether that’s reasonable code is certainly a matter of debate. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's just a toy example, never mind.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger That's the point. Find an example that is reasonable, not a toy, where the chained assignment would make sense, have a clearly unambiguous meaning, and where chained assignment is clearly superior to two separate assignments.

Comment: @j6t There's no need to be "significantly better", it's just more convenient. I've removed "reasonable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While returning a reference from `operator=` is the common and reasonable way for implementations, keep in mind that `valarray` is a rarely used and an unsupported library. See [C++ valarray vs. vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602451/c-valarray-vs-vector) for more detailed answers on this topic.

From one of the answers:

> ISTR that the main reason it wasn't removed from the standard is that nobody took the time to evaluate the issue thoroughly and write a proposal to remove it.

Even before going into debates about opinions, there are bugs in the current implementation. See [assigning to gslice_array gives runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899217/assigning-to-gslice-array-gives-runtime-error) for instance.

Comment: There must be a reason for the assignment operator to return `void`, you doesn't answer my question. Also, I think it's a great tool for optimizing performance.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger Why not void? You are calling the assignment operator of a `slice_array`. The common return value should have been the `slice_array` itself, which is already assigned by some values. In order for your example to work correctly, the return value should have been `const T&` or `const valarray<T>&`. While yours is not a bad idea, it is opinion based and is against common expectation.

Comment: What's the problem? For example, the assignment operators of another proxy class `std::bitset::reference` are `reference& operator=( bool x ) noexcept;` and `reference& operator=( const reference& x ) noexcept;`.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger `bitset::reference` has implicit cast to `bool`. To get the same effect, `slice_array` should have an implicit cast to `valarray` which means an invisible costly copy operation.

Comment: I don't understand why the conversion is needed, the returned `slice_array` itself can be used for assignment to other `slice_array`s or `valarray`s, which is also the purpose of returning itself.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger `slice_array::operator=(slice_array)` is not implemented. I think the standards committee just did not care. They would need to implement all subscript operators for all helper classes (`slice_array`, `gslice_array`, `indirect_array`, `mask_array`) with a gain of practically nothing. You can add one more line to achieve what you want anyway.

Comment: But there is `const slice_array& operator=(const slice_array&) const;` The assignment operators are used to assign to the referenced elements, not to itself.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger You are right here. As long as the subscripts are `slice_array`, the chained assignment works too. If the assignment operator for other helper classes were implemented, returning `*this` would make sense. But as is, making `slice = slice = val` work and `gslice = slice = val` an error brings confusion. Why did the committe decided not to implement them? Well, I agree with you here that they should be implemented. Which makes us come to the beginning of this answer :)

Comment: @Blackteahamburger Sorry about my erroneous `slice_array::operator=(slice_array)` comment. It all boils down to *"Why `slice_array::operator=(gslice_array)` and similar functions are not implemented?"*. Your questions are pretty good by the way. Keep it up!

Comment: However, `slice = gslice` doesn't work either, because they are different kinds of slices. So maybe it's just one of the odd designs of the committee, no good reason. I'm going to propose a fix & extension to `valarray` instead of continuing to ask why here.